# UCC28C44 flyback start-up problem

Tags: power-supply, power, current, flyback, discharge

I have a problem with a design of a flyback converter for a power supply. I am using UCC28C44 PWM IC. Converter should star up with at least 200V and VDD should be charged to 14V when 15V should appear on the output and that output should take over the supply of the IC. However, as soon as VDD reached 14 or 15V it starts going down to 9V, which is the lower threshold for the IC to turn off. The IC turns of, the VDD is again charged to 14V, it goes down again and so on in cycle. I have notices that there is no current flowing in the 15V secondary winding so that might be a problem. There is a load on start-up, so I am not trying to run a no load start-up since I've seen that some people had issues with no-load startup.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening and what is wrong?

The schematics is below:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Where is your primary bias winding?

Comment: Are your SMPS_GND and POWER_GND nets connected somewhere?

Comment: The grounds were not connected indeed, not my fault, I connected someone else's work. :)

New problem appeared:

Snubber circuit exploded. All my resistors are dead now. All resistors are 0.125W resistors and 1.8kOhm which might be too small.

Comment: There are no isolation requirements on this one? Primary is connected to secondary. How on earth did you end up with 10.8 kohm snubber? What's your primary voltage?

Comment: What load did you have connected? What are the details of the transformer?

Comment: @winny As I said, snubber was the problem, it was not sized well, not my design. I calculated a 48k snubber, but I put 100k and it was enough. 

Primary voltage is anywhere from 200V to 900V with nominal being 625V.

Comment: @Andyaka Load is around 7ohm. What do you mean by details?

Comment: Well, from where I'm sat the only details I see are two black blobs and some thin lines. However, from your last comment, can it be assumed that your problem solved now? If not, clear out all the old stuff and state specifically where you are and what the problem is. If solved through comments then explain it has been solved.

Comment: 900 V input with 1200 V MOSFET, that's going to be interesting! What's your flyback voltage? How much leakage inductance? Again, you have bridged the isolation primary-secondary. Is this intentional?